# aws cloudformation template sns sqs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I've defined an SNS topic, an SQS queue, and an SNS subscription resource in a Cloudformation stack. All three are in the same stack, same region, and same AWS account.

```
Resources:
  SqsQueue:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties:
      QueueName: 'some-queue'
  SnsTopic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties:
      TopicName: 'some-topic'
  SnsSubscription:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
    Properties:
      Endpoint: !GetAtt [SqsQueue, Arn]
      Protocol: sqs
      TopicArn: !Ref SnsTopic
```

When I run the stack, all three resources are created successfully, but when I publish a message from SNS, it's never received by the SQS queue.

I've been following this link (https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sqs-sns-subscribe-cloudformation/) and to my knowledge I've done everything I've needed to. What else am I missing?

Thanks!

**Additional info**

- If I delete the subscription that Cloudformation created via the console and then create a new one via the console, messages are published fine. So it must be something incorrect about the subscription.
- I used the AWS CLI to compare the properties of the subscription created by the Cloudformation template to the one created by the console. They are the exact same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a policy to allow the SNS topic to publish to your queue. Something like this:

```yaml
  SnsToQueuePolicy:
    Type: AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy
    Properties: 
      Queues:
        - !Ref SqsQueue
      PolicyDocument: 
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Sid: allow-sns-messages
            Effect: Allow
            Principal: '*'
            Resource: !GetAtt SqsQueue.Arn
            Action: SQS:SendMessage,
            Condition: 
              ArnEquals:
                aws:SourceArn: !Ref SnsTopic
```

Comment: Adding the policy worked. Shame AWS' documentation is so poor. Nowhere does it mention that sns topics and sqs queues in the same region and account need an explicit policy doc. Rather, it says you only need that if you're doing cross-region subscriptions.

Comment: @JasonWadsworth   +1 but Syntax Error on the Action:  Line.   There should be no comma at the end.  Great Answer thanks.